# open browser instance from $ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to open a new browser instance popup to show the contents of a file so not staying in the same page?

```
    $(document).ready(function (event) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/Index"
        });

    })

 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return File(@"C:\TextFile1.txt", "text/plain");
    }
```

Comment: Is my solution working for you? So please accept or post a comment whats not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about without ajax?

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    window.open('/Home/Index', 'Window name')
})
```

If you require ajax, because you need to POST data

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/Index",
        success: function( data ) {
           var win = window.open('about:blank', 'Window name');
           $(win.document.body).append(data);
        }
    });
})
```